What is the difference in the output of new URL(import.meta.url).href when using Webpack compared to Vite?
I have a question regarding the behavior of new URL(import.meta.url).href in different build tools.

In my Webpack project, it returns a file path like file:///...
In my Vite project, it returns a URL like http://localhost:5173/...
Can anyone explain to me why there is this difference? How can I do that if I want my Webpack project also to return a URL like http://localhost:8080? I'm not sure what keywords to search for.

The key difference is in how Webpack and Vite handle import.meta.url:
Vite returns HTTP URLs (e.g., "http://localhost:5173/src/example.js")
Webpack returns file paths (e.g., "file:///path/to/project/example.js")
To make Webpack return HTTP URLs like Vite, configure output.publicPath in webpack.config.js:
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '/your-prod-path/'
      : `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/`
  }
};


Thank you for your fast answer, I am using import.meta.url because I thought I could auto get http://localhost:8080  and not have to configure it.
Do you have the keyword for searching how to do this?

Let me help clarify this. If you're looking to automatically detect the current URL/origin without hardcoding it, there are a few approaches you could search for:
Search terms like "webpack dynamic public path" or "webpack auto public path"
Also you can dynamic update it. Updated my answer for dynamic publicPath configuration.

Sorry for the late response.  I cannot do that because my project will be built as a widget and then uploaded to S3 and other projects will use my project => the window.location.protocol will not work
